# The attached disk cannot be read from this computer. No treatment/recovery. Is there a way to fix an external hard drive without data loss?

Tags: terminal, ssd, external-disk, apfs, diskutil

Currently I'm using 1TB of SanDisk Proportable SSD.
Actually, this SSD had a lot of problems.

At first, it was used as exFAT, but an unrecognized situation occurred on the Mac, so it was recovered through the command CHKDISK using a Windows computer, and then changed to APFS. In the meantime, the error occurred again: "The attached disk cannot be read from this computer" and it does not connect.

It was not even repaired, so I forced the terminal to mount it, but it didn't work.

How can you use this drive without data loss?

[image]

When connected, the attached disk appears as unreadable on this computer:

[image]

The current situation is that disk2 should have about 500GB of data, but it is not visible:

[image]

I tried to force mount but it doesn't work:

[image]

It doesn't even test/recover.

I want to be able to solve it well without data loss.

Comment: The error “cannot be read” means that however it was formatted, macOS doesn’t recognize it.   The fact you said it was “converted to APFS” indicates it worked for a short time on a Mac then failed again.   Your drive controller on the USB drive probably failed.

Comment: Does it mean that the format is the only answer if the USB drive is it correct?

Comment: I’m not clear what you mean by that.

Comment: Is there any way to fix the usb drive controller?

Comment: The easiest would be to get a new enclosure and swap the drive.  However, it’s probably easier and cheaper to buy a new drive.

Comment: Then, in this case, is it not a logical failure of the external hard drive?

Comment: Unlikely.  Unless the magnetic medium is compromised, your format doesn’t just change suddenly to become unreadable.  If it works at one time, then suddenly stops, it’s most likely the electronics.

Comment: Is there any way to fix it with terminal commands?(There are still video files edited for 3 months.)

Comment: No.  This is like trying fix a car that been in an accident by changing the oil.

Comment: All right, thank you for your answer. I'll erase the data and restore the data